# Negative boost in Azure Search Profiles

Tags: search, boost, profile, azure-cognitive-search, scoring

We have been working on creating scoring profiles for our search. We need a way to "bury" or give "negative" boosts to some fields in case of types of scoring function "Magnitude", "Freshness", "Tags". We noticed that we cannot add a negative value for boost. Is there any other way to achieve this kind of behavior (burying results based the field) 
We cannot use $OrderBy because it takes precedence over the scoring profile.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that scenario by creating negative values (using an `INT` field) for the field we wanted to bury. That gave us the negative boost we needed.

I used a similar technique for Date "Freshness" too, where we counted the days from some event and the higher the number the less fresh the date is and used a "magnitude" function for it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by, "negative values". Let's say I want to bury a  product with specific "brand name" for any search keyword. What are suggesting here? can you elaborate

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

you should only set positive boosting values, as described `[here][1]`. There may be a few things you could do. The first thing I would try is to set the weight to 0 for the fields that you do not care about. In that case, they will simply not impact the relevance.

Another option: If you know that a field should not impact relevance you could simply make that field not 'searchable'.  That said, this is a property of the index definition -- so you would need to create a different index for each combination of non-searchable fields.

Depending on your scenario, you could also make a field filterable, and filter based on that field. Something like $filer=Freshenss eq 'Really Fresh'.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters) for more information on using filters.

thanks!
-Luis Cabrera

Comment: Thanks for the reply Luis. Unfortunately these techniques do not address the main issue I am talking about. We do not want to filter those results out but need a way to push them down in the results by using a negative score. We still need those results. For e.g. I you find some specific "text" in a "tag" parameter values you push it down the results list by giving it a lower score. (hence negavtive boost).
thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, in that case the best you can do is set the weight to 0 for those fields.

Answer (score 0):

For "Magnitude", "Freshness", you can set the set the range start as higher value and range end as lower value. Would this be considered as negative impact?

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have thought the about the need for this too.

One idea I have, but haven't tried, is to do a second search on just the negative keywords.  That search result will have scores as well.

Then use those scores in a function to reduce first search result scores.

(yes, it would be nicer if it could be do as part of ACS)